# ASP.NET MVC 3: Moved app into virtual directory. What do I have to change?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have been working on an MVC 3 app.  I was using VS 2010's built-in web server.

Today, for various reasons, I was asked to move it into a virtual directory and run it under IIS 7, still on my development PC.

Now that its URL is `localhost/MyVirtualDirectory` as opposed to `localhost:12345`, what do I need to change to make routing work, and where?

I'm not using any raw HTML anchor tags or redirects, just `@Html.ActionLink` and so on.  According to what I've read, if I've been doing things the MVC way, this change should have been transparent.

But right at the beginning, the post-authentication redirection fails.  On successful authentication, it's supposed to return the result of

```
this.RedirectToAction("index", "Home")
```

You guessed it:  instead of `/MyVirtualDirectory/Home` the redirection goes to `/Home`.  Which fails.

So something is missing that needs to be set up.  What is it?

Comment: What does your `RegisterRoutes` looks like in your Global.asax?

Comment: You probably configured IIS incorrectly. This should be completely transparent.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov OK, I'm prepared to believe that. Do MVC apps have to be set up differently from WebForms apps?

Comment: @AnnL., absolutely no. ASP.NET MVC is simply an ordinary ASP.NET application. Nothing different. So if you know how to setup an ASP.NET application in IIS you know how to setup an ASP.NET MVC application in IIS. And if you don't know it's a question you could ask on http://serverfault.com which is better suited for server configuration questions like this.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov  Thought I knew how, but it's been a while.  I'll visit serverfault.com.  And thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In IIS, choose your virtual directory and "Convert to Application." Also, if you are using the default route map in your Global.asax it should read something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Reasoning: If you put your MVC application in a sub-directory of another application then IIS will consider the root of that other application instead of the root of your MVC application. If that is the behavior that you want (unlikely) then you need to modify your Global.asax to take that into account:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "MyVirtualDirectory/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, according to IIS my virtual directory is already an application. I've got IIS7.5, and under the Default Web Site Content view my virtual directory has a "type" of Application.

Comment: Okay, when you wrote virtual directory in your question I took that as a possible indicator that you had not specified the directory as an application. You might check app pool settings, etc, but as mentioned previously this probably becomes more a serverfault.com question.

Comment: I found my problem, which turned out to be an incorrectly-derived URL in a redirect statement.  Yours is a good answer to the question asked, though -- I just happened to be wrong about what was really going on.  Thank you very much for answering!