# MVC Publish to host is adding extra sub folders

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subdirectory

I'm publishing an MVC 3 site to a go daddy account.  I'm using the FTP Publish utility in VS 2010.  The site publishes "okay".  But here is the issue:

On my local machine, when I run it the web address is:
    localhost/Student/Create

On my go daddy account, I have created a subdirectory  called mvctest.
I have created a subdomain called mvctest.mysite.com that points to the virtual directory at mvctest.  This works fine.

But after I publish my site to www.mysite.com/mvctest, I am getting an additional /mvctest/ directory in all of my links.  What I want is:
mvctest.mysite.com/Student/Create
what I get is:
mvctest.mysite.com/mvctest/Student/Create

What's interesting is that if I manually type in what I want, the page loads fine.  If I've hard-coded a link to the root, it's fine, but all of my Url.Content and Html. Links add the additional mvctest directory..

I've searched all over and haven't found an answer to this dilemma. I tried  in the web.config, but I don't think that does it.  I feel like something in the FTP Publish utility in VS2010 is altering the routing structure in my global.asax file, but I'm not sure.

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is your virtual directory an application?  If it's not set as an application, IIS will treat the root of your site as the application and add the subdirectory.  See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042832/asp-net-mvc-3-moved-app-into-virtual-directory-what-do-i-have-to-change).

Comment: I fixed it!  Not sure how; I need to do more research. I've found some more posts on this issue by searching for Html.ActionLink and Application Root.  And unfortunately, nobody seems to have an answer.  Yes, my subdirectory is checked to be the application root.  I recycled the App Pool, but no go.   I then changed the Pipeline to Integrated, and that appears to have solved it.   I'm going to take out the <rewrite> settings in the web.config and see if it comes back, but I finally got it working right.

Answer (score 0):

The following solved the same issue for me and is quoted from a blog post I found ([source](http://kaushikcsharpandsharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/05/solution-for-aspnet-routing-on-godaddy.html)):

So now for the solution, and I probably should have mentioned this at the beginning but hopefully you’re using IIS7 with the URL rewriting module installed (it is installed by default when you use IIS7 on GoDaddy).
Simply add the following into your web.config’s system.webServer element:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Remove Virtual Directory">
      <match url=".*" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

All this does is “rewrite” the URL with itself. This causes URL Rewrite to add the original URL (the one with no folder name) to a ServerVariable which is used by ASP.NET MVC to generate other URLs.