# .NET routing not including full path to app directory?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm pretty new to ASP.NET applications, and this app is being served by IIS (I believe version 10).  When navigating to my site at `https://{host}/Dashboard`, this component loads; however, it fails to load any child components and throws a 404, for example it attempts to take the view for `/Defects/YearOverYear` from `{host}/Defects/YearOverYear`, as opposed to `{host}/Dashboard/Defects/YearOverYear`, which is where that particular view is actually located.

I've seen talk of this being related to routing from the root directory instead of the application directory, and I've also seen some mention of this being either a config issue with IIS, or a config issue in the .csproj file (which does Visual Studio not include the properties in your project config in the final build anywhere?), but having taken a few shots in the dark I'm not sure where to go from here.

This project doesn't have a route handler, but it does have a route config that works on the production server as is, so I'm pretty certain it's a config issue elsewhere either during build or deployment.

I can include any extra info or config files, I'm just not sure which at the moment to put here.

Comment: You can get some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8042832/asp-net-mvc-3-moved-app-into-virtual-directory-what-do-i-have-to-change

Comment: @LexLi I appreciate the tip - that post is definitely of a similar quality problem, but unfortunately there is no custom route handling (only route mappings) in this application and it is already treated by IIS as an application.  The broken routing started to work again when I added a nested virtual directory, though, which was odd.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is something wrong with the project router. What is the root directory of the project publishment? What framework is your project type based on?
Mostly cases, if your project based on the Angular/Vuejs, there are some settings for the root directory in the assets, thus the relative address works. Such as
[Vue.js routes serving from subdirectory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43918367/vue-js-routes-serving-from-subdirectory)
Besides, try to convert your subdirectory to application. This will enable the child folder to an actual application.
[image]
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: The router was my first thought, too - this application doesn't have any custom router handling, and the route mapping that exists works for the production server; and what's more, most of the action requests work (for scripts, assets, and even the html of the parent component itself), except for this one strange behavior.  The app is already configured as such in IIS and it is just an asp.net webapp - nothing special.